# error messages during running gamboost using caret

Tags: r, gam, r-caret

I am running `gamboost` using `Caret`. The model was generated, but the running process gives the following error message as shown below. I am not clear what does that mean.

```
rd<- train(formula0, data = df.clean,method = "gamBoost",trControl = train_control,metric="RMSE")
```

The model looks like this

[image]

The error messages are

[image]

Comment: Instead of providing screenshots of the error, it is a better idea to copy and paste the messages. This way, other people searching for the same error will be able to find the answer. Also, you can provide your dataset by posting the results of `dput(df.clean)`, which would make it easier to debug the error.

Comment: I think the only way to figure this out is with a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo`.